# JButton Default Selection Color

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want to change the default color when selecting a JButton. Per default it is "lightblue". When pressing a JButton the background changes for some 0.2 seconds to lightblue.

[image: Default color]

I don't want to `setBackground()`. I want to change the default property. Is there something like:

```
JButton button = new JButton(text);
button.setSelectionColor(Color);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by the LAF.

You might be able to use:

```
UIManager.put("Button.select", new Color( 0, 255, 0) );
```

at the start of your program before you create your buttons.

However, this will apply to all buttons in your application.

Comment: Ty very much. this is what i searched for :)